# Waiting for property loaded

Tags: javascript

I'm just wondering if something like this is possible in Javascript.

```
var Module = function(){
    var _ajaxLoaded = false;
    var _property = null;
    return {
        init : function(){
            // starting ajax request here
            $.getJSON('requesturl', function(data) {
                _property = data.property;
                _ajaxLoaded = true;
            });
        },
        property : function(){
            if(_ajaxLoaded){
                return _property;
            }
            // stop processing here and wait till  ajax request is finished


            // loop till ajax is finished
            return this.property();
        }
    }

 }();

Module.init();
alert(Module.property());
```

I know that it is possible to have a callback in the init function and wait for that. But this example would allow me to just ask for the property without knowing if it is even there.

-- EDIT --

I'm pretty sure I just should use a callback in the init function. It simply a better coding structure. But I really wonder if it is even possible to do, if I had no other possibility.
I added following line:

```
      // loop till ajax is finished
      return this.property();
```

Could this somehow work or would I end up in an endless loop because Javascript doesn't even have time to process the ajax call(single threading?)? Haven't tested it yet.

No doubt, it is bad coding and I wouldn't use it, but I'm just curious.

Comment: You *could* make a synchronous AJAX call, but it would lock up the browser until it was done, and is discouraged.  Why can't you use a callback in `$.getJSON`?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `var _ajaxLoaded = false;`?

Comment: Browser scripting is event based. When something is not ready, you bind a handler which is invoked when that something becomes ready.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas yes, should be. I wrote this code just as an example

Comment: If you ever had an AJAX error, this would result in an endless loop.

Comment: In this case I doesn't want to make the AJAX call synchronous because, as you said, it looks up the browser. 

But I wouldn't mind if the Browser get looked up when a Javascript file tries to access the property.

I have to change a lot of coding lines (not written by my self) if I'm using a callback function.

Comment: @HerroRygar, I could set the _AjaxLoaded variable to true on an AJAX fail, if jQuery triggers an event for this. Otherwise I have to implement an Ajax timeout with setTimeout(function() {_ajaxLoaded = true}, 5000). It would return null in this case.